# Book application program in Java using linked list

Tags: java

I am making a code in which the program shows some options like insert Book, delete Book etc.
The program asks us to enter certain details about a book by Insert method.

Once I enter details it goes back and show the options again.

When I choose search method it asks me search by title or search by ISBN or search by author. I choose an option and program works perfectly.

I made a method `updateBook`. It works fine but when I search for my UPDATED INFORMATION it shows nothing.

How to resolve this problem?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BookApplication {
    static Book head, pointer;
    static Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Welcome to Smart Book Store");
        System.out.println("Please choose an option from the list below");
        int choice = 0;
        do {

            System.out.println("1. Insert Book\n2. Delete Book\n3. Search Book\n4. Update Book\n5. View Book\n6. Exit");
            choice = scan.nextInt();
            try {
                choice = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                switch (choice) {
                case 1:
                    addBook();
                    break;
                case 2:
                case 3:
                    searchBook();
                    break;
                case 4:
                    updateBook();
                    break;
                case 5:
                    break;
                case 6:
                    scan.close();
                    System.exit(0);
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("Please choose from 1 to 5");
                    break;

                }
            }
        } while (true);
    }

    static void addBook() {
        if (head == null) {
            String details[] = enterDetails();
            pointer = new Book(details[0], details[1], details[2]);
            head = pointer;
            pointer.next = null;
        } else {
            String details[] = enterDetails();

            pointer.next = new Book(details[0], details[1], details[2]);
            pointer = (Book) pointer.next;
        }
    }

    static String[] enterDetails() {
        String[] details = new String[4];
        try {

            String title;
            String ISBN;
            String authors;

            System.out.println("Please enter Book title");
            title = scan.nextLine();

            System.out.println("Please enter ISBN of book");
            ISBN = scan.nextLine();

            System.out.println("Please enter book's Author(s)");
            authors = scan.nextLine();

            details[0] = title;
            details[1] = ISBN;
            details[2] = authors;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return details;
    }

    private static void searchBook() {
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("1. Search by TITLE");
        System.out.println("2. Search by ISBN");
        System.out.println("3. Search by AUTHOR");

        int choice = 0;
        choice: try {
            choice = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("PLEASE ENTER VALUE BETWEEN 1 - 3");
            break choice;
        }

        switch (choice) {
        case 1:
            System.out.println("Please enter Title of BOOK");
            String title = scan.nextLine();
            if (head == null) {
                System.out.println("List is EMPTY !");
                return;
            } else {
                System.out.println();
                System.out.println("BOOK(S) IN THE SYSTEM ARE: ");
                System.out.println();
                pointer = head;
                while (pointer != null) {
                    if (pointer.title.equals(title)) {
                        System.out.println(pointer.getBook());

                    }
                    pointer = (Book) pointer.next;
                }
            }
            break;
        case 2:
            System.out.println("Please enter ISBN of BOOK");
            String ISBN = scan.nextLine();
            if (head == null) {
                System.out.println("List is EMPTY !");
                return;
            } else {
                System.out.println();
                System.out.println("BOOK(S) IN THE SYSTEM ARE: ");
                System.out.println();
                pointer = head;
                while (pointer != null) {
                    if (pointer.ISBN.equals(ISBN)) {
                        System.out.println(pointer.getBook());
                        break;
                    }
                    pointer = (Book) pointer.next;
                }
            }
            break;
        case 3:
            System.out.println("Please enter Author(s) of BOOK");
            String authors = scan.nextLine();
            if (head == null) {
                System.out.println("List is EMPTY !");
                return;
            } else {
                System.out.println();
                System.out.println("BOOK(S) IN THE SYSTEM ARE: ");
                System.out.println();
                pointer = head;
                while (pointer != null) {
                    if (pointer.authors.contains(authors)) {
                        System.out.println(pointer.getBook());
                        break;
                    }
                    pointer = (Book) pointer.next;
                }
            }
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("PLEASE ENTER VALUE BETWEEN 1 - 5");
        }

    }

    static void updateBook() {
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("1. Update TITLE");
        System.out.println("2. Update ISBN");
        System.out.println("3. Update AUTHOR");

        int choice = 0;
        choice: try {
            choice = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("PLEASE ENTER VALUE BETWEEN 1 - 3");
            break choice;
        }
        switch (choice) {
        case 1:
            System.out.println("Please update Title of BOOK");
            String another1 = scan.nextLine();
            if (head == null) {
                System.out.println("Title not Updated !");
                return;
            } else {
                System.out.println();
                System.out.println("Your new title is: " + another1);
                System.out.println();
                pointer = head;
                while (pointer != null) {
                    if (pointer.title.equals(another1)) {
                        System.out.println(pointer.getBook());
                        break;
                    }
                    pointer = (Book) pointer.next;
                }
            }
        case 2:

            System.out.println("Please update ISBN of BOOK");
            String ISBN = scan.nextLine();
            if (head == null) {
                System.out.println("Isbn not updated !");
                return;
            } else {
                System.out.println();
                int aISBN = Integer.parseInt(ISBN.trim());

                System.out.println("Your book's updated ISBN is: " + aISBN);
                System.out.println();
                pointer = head;
                while (pointer != null) {
                    if (pointer.ISBN.equals(aISBN)) {
                        System.out.println(pointer.getBook());
                        break;
                    }
                    pointer = (Book) pointer.next;
                }
            }
        case 3:
            System.out.println("Please enter Author(s) of BOOK");

            String upauthor1 = scan.nextLine();
            if (head == null) {
                System.out.println("List is EMPTY !");
                return;
            } else {
                System.out.println();
                System.out.println("Book's Updated author is: " + upauthor1);

                System.out.println();
                pointer = head;
                while (pointer != null) {
                    if (pointer.authors.contains(upauthor1)) {
                        System.out.println(pointer.getBook());

                        break;
                    }
                    pointer = (Book) pointer.next;

                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my another class.

```
public class Book {
    String authors;

    final String ISBN;
    final String title;
    public Object next;

    Book(String title, String ISBN, String authors) {
        this.title = title;

        this.authors = authors;
        this.ISBN = ISBN ;
    }

    public String getBook() {
        return "Book Title: " + this.title + "\n" + "Book ISBN: " + this.ISBN + "\n" + "Book Authors: " + this.authors + "\n" ;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because you dont save the new data. It's obvious because you can add a book and update it. If you search for the updated info, there is nothing, but if you search for the old versions (pre-update) there it is.

```java
pointer = head;
while (pointer != null) {
    if (pointer.title.equals(another1)) {
        System.out.println(pointer.getBook());
        break;
    }
    pointer = (Book) pointer.next;
}
```

You just go through the list and expect the change to be done.

You should first have to ask for book info, search if it exists and then ask for the new data.